# Изменение прав всех каналов discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-jda

```
const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'ssssss');

    if (!muteRole) {
        muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                    name: "ssssss",
                    color: "#514f48",
                    permissions: []
                }
            })
            message.guild.channels.cache.get( async (channel) => {
                await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                    ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                    SPEAK: false,
                    CONNECT: false,
                })
        })
    }
```

Мне нужно чтобы в случае если роль мута не найдена, оно создавало роль и сразу изменяло все права всех каналов, добавляя туда созданную роль с правами
SEND_MESSAGES: false,
ADD_REACTIONS: false,
SPEAK: false,
CONNECT: false,

Ошибка Uncaught Promise Error:  TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [await is only valid in async function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847829/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ошибка возникает при попытке переназначить const, исправляется использование let вместо const.
2. Для того чтобы права изменились во всех каналах, достаточно сделать перебор методом forEach.

```js
let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'ssssss');

    if(!muteRole) {
        muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "ssssss",
                color: "#514f48",
                permissions: []
            }
        })
        message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
            channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                SPEAK: false,
                CONNECT: false,
            })
        });
    }
```